# How to architech heroku app for workers with wildly varying runtimes?

Tags: python, multithreading, heroku

I'm building a web application that has some long-running jobs to do, and some very short.  The jobs are invoked by users on the website, and can run anywhere from a few seconds to several hours.  The spawned job needs to provide status updates to the user via the website.

I'm new to heroku, and am thinking the proper approach is to spawn a new dyno for each background task, and to communicate status via database or a memcache record. Maybe?

My question is whether this is the technically feasibly, and advisable approach?

I ask it because the documentation has a different mindset: that the worker dyno pulls jobs off a queue, and if you want things to go faster you run more dynos.  I'm not sure that will work—could a 10 second job get blocked waiting for a couple of 10 hour jobs to finish?  There is a way of determining the size of the job but, again, there is a highly variable amount of work to do before it is known.

I've not found any examples suggesting it is even possible for the web dyno to run up workers ad-hoc.  Is it?  Is the solution to multi-thread the worker dyno?  Is so, what about potential memory space issues?

What's my best approach?
thx.